# Best Linux server for Worklight?

Tags: linux, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to find out which linux configuration is best for hosting Worklight Server.
Does any of us have any recent experience in installing WorkLight Server in Linux machines?
Thanks
Achintya

Comment: Is this question resolved? Please mark as Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a list of supported Linux distributions, visit:

- [Worklight 5.0.5 system requirements](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/osForProduct?deliverableId=1322605181306)
- [Worklight 5.0.6 system requirements](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/osForProduct?deliverableId=C2E8EF801E8711E28ACF6F870925FE36)
- [Worklight 6.0.0 system requirements](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/osForProduct?deliverableId=1343665214557)